# ExceptionHandling in JSF 2.x, access SessionScoped managed bean from another and redirect

Tags: jsf, redirect, exception

I did some research on how to get this done, I found some isolated solutions, but I was not able to figure out, how to combine them and what way is consisted as best practice. I am using tomcat and jsf 2.x.

Scenario:
I have a session scoped bean, mycontrollerA. The controller relates to myviewa.xhtml. After hitting a commandLink on viewA, the action mycontrollerA.doThis() got triggered. In this method I want to use try-catch and if an exception occurs, I want to redirect to my exception report view 'exception.xhtml'. The related controller ExceptionController has an attribute 'message' and I want to set the corresponding value in myControllerA.

Problems: I got an error if I try to grab my exceptionController bean. I guess, that it is just not there, because it never got initialized. I hope that there is a common way to grab a SessionScoped bean from another SessionScoped bean, which handles this 'create if necessary'behaviour out of the box. Moreover I think there my redirection-code could be improved.

Thanks in advance.

```
public String doThis() {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException("TestExc");
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    //ExceptionController exceptionController = (ExceptionController) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("exceptionController");
    //exceptionController.setMessage("Fehlerinfo: " + e.getMessage());
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("exception.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    return null;
}

@ManagedBean(name = "exceptionController")
@SessionScoped
public class ExceptionController { ... }
```

Comment: First of all, is there any special reason for this `mycontrollerA` bean to be `@SessionScoped`? I ask that because it looks you are linking it with specific view, so it can be more convenient to have `@ViewScoped` annotation. Having said that, you can reference a `@SessionScoped` bean from a `@ViewScoped` one using `@ManagedProperty` annotation. But remember that this bean won't be initialized unless you  do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to resolve the bean via ELResolver:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext el = fc.getELContext();
ExceptionController exCtrl = (ExceptionController) el.getELResolver()
    .getValue(el, null, "exceptionController");
```

Your problem probably is, that the bean was not created before and therefore it is not yet in the session. With the ELResolver approach it should be created.